# Collection of finite unions of half-open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are an algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Similar, but not the same as [An example of an algebra but not a sigma algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737395/an-example-of-an-algebra-but-not-a-sigma-algebra).

This is from Yeh's *Real Analysis*, 3rd edition, Example 3 (from section 1.1):

> In $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $\mathcal{R}$ be the collection of all rectangles of the type $(a_1, b_1] \times (a_2, b_2]$ where $-\infty \leq a_i < b_i \leq \infty$ for $i = 1, 2$ with the understanding that $(a_i, \infty] = (a_i, \infty)$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of all finite unions of members of $\mathcal{R}$... It is easily verified that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. However $\mathcal{A}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

My attempt at a proof:

> If $A \in \mathcal{R}$ is arbitrary, then $A$ is a one-set union of a member of $\mathcal{R}$, hence $A \in \mathcal{A}$. Thus $\mathcal{R} \subset \mathcal{A}$.
>
> Define $\varnothing$ as the union of zero members of $\mathcal{R}$ so that $\varnothing \in \mathcal{R}$ and thus $\varnothing \in \mathcal{A}$.
>
> Let $$K = \bigcup_{j=1}^{n}(a_{1j}, b_{1j}] \times (a_{2j}, b_{2j}] = \bigcup_{j=1}^{n}R_j \in \mathcal{A}$$
>
> Observe $$K^c = \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}R_j \right)^c = \bigcap_{j=1}^{n}R_j^c\text{.}$$

I originally had a sketch for this part which I now realize is incorrect. Could someone please provide a next step for approaching this part of the problem (i.e., closure under complements)?

The closure under unions I've figured out.

Comment: First, show that the complement of a rectangle is the union of finitely many rectangles. Then show that the intersection of two rectangles is a rectangle or empty. Then note that a finite intersection of finite unions is a finite union of finite intersections.